# what does B/G mean in trucking?

Tags: truck

In a truck driving license guide there are some terms that I don't understand. They are :

- Power steering B / G
- Water pump B / G
- Alternator B / G
- Air compressor B / G

I know what Water pump,Alternator,Air compressor,Power steering are but I don't know what is B / G .

If you don't understand the question or need more details , please ask .

Comment: I would guess at "Belt" / "Gear" but have no basis for this guess other than it seams likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Commercial Driver License manual, you have to be able to identify whether an engine accesory is belt or gear driven when you do your pre-
trip inspection.